# Web fonts look worse after deleting MS Office

Tags: font

I recently deleted my MS Office 2011 and decided to use only iWork or Libre Office or LaTeX. The problem is, now fonts on all browsers look worse than before. I have no idea why this is so, it only started after I deleted Office and its fonts, and I don't even remember how they looked like before I installed Office.

Is there any way to enhance the fonts used for web browsers? Fonts in all other applications look fine.

Comment: I don’t know why, but there was a folder called Fonts (Disabled) next to the /Library/Fonts folder. I had tried both solutions but they didn’t work. Then I moved the Fonts (Disabled) fonts (Times New Roman and Arial and Verdana etc.) to the /Library/Fonts folder, and it’s all normal again. But the tips were useful — they solved other problems I didn’t know I had.

Answer (score 2):

Your font are probably corrupt. But no worries, you can restore them with almost no effort :)

1. Open fontbook
2. Select all the fonts
3. Right click and select validate. All the fonts Office installed that are bad will show warnings.
4. Remove those, and you'll be good as new without a reinstall of anything.

Let me know if this helps you out!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that Office substituted system fonts when installed, and the uninstaller had them removed or disabled. You could try restoring the standard (system) fonts by opening **Font Book** and choosing **Restore Standard Fonts...** from the File menu.